# NullPointerException when calling Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: android, tabs, searchview

I am trying to implement SearchView on the Activity ToolBar. Here I need to search the product under the Tab Fragment from the MainActivity.While clicking Search icon the app is crashed and I got the error as follows.

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
```

What does it mean? What did I do to fix this bug? Please Help me.

**UPDATE:**

```
  public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();  // Got error in this line
    for (Fragment myFragment : fragmentList) {
        if (myFragment.getUserVisibleHint()) {
            return myFragment;
        }
    }
    return fragmentList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code which generates this error?

Comment: Well the error message is quite clear. The object on which you call getChildFragmentManager is null. Post some code how you use it.

Comment: Please check my edited codes @RvdK

Comment: Please check my edited code @PrerakSola

Comment: @ParamaSudha Please post only _relevant_ code

Comment: Edited.Please Check it @RvdK

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear. You are calling `getChildFragmentManager` on an object which is `null`.

In your case, it means the fragmentmanager could not find the fragment with ID: `R.id.container`

```
Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
```